# Net Core Versions questions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm new to .Net core. I cannot find a list of versions for Net Core SDK.
I read that there are three: 1.0.0 , 1.1.0 (current) and 2.0.0 (future)

I followed official documentation on how to work with net core in Visual Studio 2015, and get it working, but still I cannot understand versions.

In a library I have developed using net core, it says the version is '1.0.0-preview2-003131'
Is it 1.0.0 ? 1.0.1? Is it officially released or just a preview?

Also, I have a unit tests project using Net Framework 4.6.2. to test my dll. Is it ok if I want to test classes developed under Net Core? Is it the right way?

Finally, I developed an ASP Net Core MVC web application, that uses my net core dll, it is using "netcoreapp1.0". They are working fine together, as expected.
But how can I learn about compatibility between my net core dll and different net framework versions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comparison and compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)

**Also, I have a unit tests project using Net Framework 4.6.2. to test my dll. Is it ok if I want to test classes developed under Net Core? Is it the right way?**

IMO sure its fine to unit test those classes using that framework. Would I do it this way? No. I would have my unit tests running under the same framework.

**But how can I learn about compatibility between my net core dll and different net framework versions?**

See the above GUIDE

Answer (score 2):

You can find all dot net core releases [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/releases).

'1.0.0-preview2-003131' is indeed a preview version, the latest release is 1.0.4.

I don't know if you can test a dot net core project using a test project that runs 4.6.2, but there's a net core [library](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test.md) for testing, called xUnit.

You can reference 4.6 libraries inside donet core, you can learn more [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx).

Comment: Good, I will move to 1.0.4

Comment: I installed it, and changed from '1.0.0-preview2-003131' to '1.0.1' in my global.json. But cannot make it work. Error: error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\d
otnet\sdk\1.0.1\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import>
 declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.